New Ubuntu user on 24.4.1 and cannot hear sound anymore
I'm relatively new to Linux and decided to put Ubuntu on a Chromebook. There's no sound at all and I've tried all troubleshooting possible (that I could find) like alsamixer and trying to reinstall pulse audio but nothing has worked and yeah, I'm just at a loss, help. When I connect headphones, the sound does not come out of the headphones, it instead comes out of the speaker.
lynea@mycomputerrrr:~$  lshw -C multimedia
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-multimedia:0 UNCLAIMED  
       description: Multimedia controller
       product: JasperLake IPU
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 5
       bus info: pci@0000:00:05.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:91000000-91ffffff
  *-multimedia:1
       description: Multimedia audio controller
       product: Jasper Lake HD Audio
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=sof-audio-pci-intel-icl latency=64
       resources: irq:135 memory:7fd24000-7fd27fff memory:7fc00000-7fcfffff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.

